# Heat map and correlation among variables

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, correlation, heatmap

I would have a question on heat map and correlation among variables.
I created this heat map, looking at possible correlation among variables and target. I got very small values.
I wanted to set a small threshold, e.g., 0.05, for selecting features.
Do you think it makes sense, or should I exclude all of them?

[image]

Comment: Do you mean you want to filter input variables with a high correlation among them? Or exclude input variables with low correlation with the target?

Comment: I have tried to select highly correlated features as follows:
important_features = correlation_target[correlation_target >0.05] . The model improved its performance, but I do not know if this kind of selection can make sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the info you provide, it seems you are carrying feature selection based on the correlation between your predictor variables and the target. 
This is correct as a type of feature selection ([see here](http://sklearn.feature_selection%20import%20f_regression)) in the family of **univariate filter selection**, although not the only one. It is fast and intuitive, although you can have a look at other methods. You might also be interested in:

- ***variance threshold*** selection (also per input feature, univariate filter method): it assumes that higher variance in a feature values could mean more prediction power
- ***sequential backward selection*** ([look here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.SequentialFeatureSelector.html#sklearn.feature_selection.SequentialFeatureSelector)): it means more performance cost, but features are judged in subsets (not independently as above) and is ok if you don't have many features (as it seems to be)

There are ***many other strategies*** for feature selection (you might want to check for [this source](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.feature_selection))

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and explanation, German.